# Android ; Confirm app exit

Tags: java, android

fairly new to Android development.

I made a function for the user to call a phone number, which exit the applications and open the dialer.

Until here, everythings okay. But now I'd like to add a confirm dialog when the user clicks the button to warn him that calling will exit the application. ("Calling will exit the app. Are you sure ? Confirm | Canel")

I looked around but haven't found any clear examples. Any help would be appreciated, here's what I have so far.

```
final String phoneNumber;
phoneNumber = "5555555555";

ImageButton callButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btnCall);

callButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v) {
        try {
            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+phoneNumber));
            startActivity(callIntent);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException activityException) {
            Log.e("Calling a Phone Number", "Call failed", activityException);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do what your are looking for:

```
    callButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    if(which == Dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE)
                    {
                        try {
                            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+phoneNumber));
                            startActivity(callIntent);
                        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException activityException) {
                            Log.e("Calling a Phone Number", "Call failed", activityException);
                        }
                    }
                }           
            };

            new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext())
            .setMessage("Are you sure you want to leave the application?")
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", listener)
            .setNegativeButton("No", listener)
            .show();
        }
    }
```

Edited to replace context with v.getContext()

Answer (score 2):

You can use an Alert Dialog that ships with Yes and No buttons:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

alert.setTitle("Title");
alert.setMessage("Message");

// Set an EditText view to get user input 
final EditText input = new EditText(this);
alert.setView(input);

alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
  String value = input.getText();
  // Do something with value!
  }
});

alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
    // Canceled.
  }
});

alert.show();
```

You could insert this after `startActivity(callIntent);`in your try/catch.

Answer (score 1):

You should use AlertDialog.Builder: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AlertDialog